# CrmAddIn crashes/ Mail Merge not registering camapaign activities

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I´m working on the migration for a CRM 4.0 on-premise system to CRM 2013 in which one of the most used features is the campaign module.Now I´m facing a problem with mail merge, when I try to distribute a campaign activity:
The process starts, the mails are generated and sent, but the window for tracking the campaign activities is not  presented and the process crashes in background. I already un- and resintalled the Outlook client, but this didn´t resolve tghe problem.
In the event log I find the following entry:

Faulting application name: Microsoft.Crm.Application.Outlook.WebFormsHost.exe, version: 6.0.0.809, time stamp: 0x523d509d
Faulting module name: crmaddin.dll, version: 6.0.0.809, time stamp: 0x523d5152
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000a75a
Faulting process id: 0x748
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf2bcd4fa6bcd8
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\res\web\bin\Microsoft.Crm.Application.Outlook.WebFormsHost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\bin\crmaddin.dll
Report Id: b9413ac9-97c0-11e3-80d3-000c2982ff89
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:

The CRM System is Version 6.0.0.809

and I´m using Office 2010.

Has anyone faced this problem before?

Comment: A Re-Install of UpdateRollup 1 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Possible cause could be the corruption of file - Microsoft.Crm.Application.Outlook.WebFormsHost.exe located here - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\Client\res\web\bin\

Do a clean uninstall by deleting the Microsoft Dynamics CRM folder from programs file and reinstall CRM client later. You can also try to repair it using suggestion here - http://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/xrminadynamicsbox/archive/2014/02/09/solution-crm-2013-outlook-client-407-proxy-authentication-required-exception.aspx

However, I would recommend a clean uninstall and reinstall.

Thanks,
Aasif